# RabbitMQ connections dropping and not recovering despite heartbeat setting

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am trying to run down a problem with consumer connections to RabbitMQ being dropped in our production environment. This problem seems to occur after running for a few days and by restarting our application it seems to connect and work fine for a few more days. My guess is that there is a period of inactivity that is causing the issue. It seems the AMQP heartbeat was designed just for this problem. We are using spring-amqp 1.3.2.RELEASE and setting the requestedHeartbeat on the ConnectionFactory to 10 however we are still seeing connections drop.

The spring-amqp client will reconnect if I completely disconnect from the internet and reconnect, or block the connection with a firewall, however it does not even seem to throw an Exception in the log when this happens in production. Of course that may be because we are using slf4j and logback for our logging mechanism and spring is using commons logging, so it is appearing in System.out and not going to the log. I have added the jcf-over-slf4j bridge to fix that but have not rolled it out yet so I do not have a stack trace to contribute.

One more piece of info about our architecture: we have HA proxy in front of RabbitMQ.

I would like to somehow put the app in debug and run within eclipse to see if the heartbeats are actually going out. I tried to verify with Wireshark but our traffic has two way SSL encryption and I haven't been able to decrypt the traffic yet.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I have been trying to run this down for weeks and I'm running out of ideas. I would greatly appreciate your input.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

on 11-Feb-2015 days ago rabbit released 3.4.4 which has support for automatic reconnections.  You could roll your own solution like we did a while back but it seems easier to just upgrade to the newest version of rabbit.

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/blob/rabbitmq_v3_4_4/projects/client/RabbitMQ.Client/src/client/impl/AutorecoveringConnection.cs

Comment: Spring AMQP has had its own auto-recovery from the beginning; rabbitmq added it in 3.3.0 but it is not compatible with Spring AMQP's recovery.

Comment: (when using Spring AMQP < 1.4).

Comment: Thanks! In our latest release we are upgrading to spring 4.1.4.RELEASE and spring-rabbit 1.4.3.RELEASE. The spring-amqp framework has done a great job in recovering from most failures so I do want to keep using it's recovery mechanism. In fact we had an outage where our RabbitMQ server was hosted recently and all of our consumers recovered fine. Thanks for pointing out the AutorecoveringConnection though.

Answer (score 2):

If you have rabbitmq's [autorecovery](https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#recovery) enabled, Spring AMQP prior to 1.4 is not compatible with it; the problem being that rabbit restores the connections/channels, but Spring AMQP doesn't know about them. Generally, though, this just causes extra connections/channels - Spring AMQP just establishes new channels. I have not heard of it causing the problems you describe.

If you can't figure it out by fixing your logging configuration, another thing to try is to jstack your process to see what the threads are doing. But you should be able to figure it out from the logs.

Comment: Thanks Gary. We are going to get our logging patch out and see if we can capture more information about it. If that doesn't give me anything I'll try the jstack suggestion. I'll give an update here when I collect all that data. Thanks for your suggestions.